# "Бывает ох как не просто!"

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно поставить запятые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь не надо никаких запятых. *"Ох как"* - цельная конструкция, употребленная в значении *"очень"*.

Answer (score 0):

В этом предложении никаких других знаков не надо, так как "ох" здесь усилительная частица

Comment: ОХ - это частица, а не междометие?

Comment: А я разве не то же самое написал?